# Trying to filter with a lambda function inside of a list comprehension

Tags: python, list, filter, lambda, list-comprehension

I am trying to remove all even indices from a list with a list comprehension. I am using a lambda function to filter the even indices, why is it not working?

Input:

```
data = [e for i, e in enumerate(raw_data) if lambda i: True if i % 2 != 0 else False]
```

Output:

```
Input In [90]
data = [e for i, e in enumerate(raw_data) if lambda i: True if i % 2 != 0]
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The output is returning a syntax error where I defined by lambda. Is it not possible to use a lambda in a list comprehension as the filter argument?

EDIT 1: I know there's no reason to use lambda when I can just put the condition directly into the list comprehension, I'm just curious as to why it didn't work.

EDIT 2: Removed useless numpy code surrounding list comprehension

EDIT 3: Removed return statements from lambda

Comment: Why use a lambda when you can just use the condition in your lambda `[... if i % 2 != 0]`? You need to call the lambda if you want to use it like this, you should either define the lambda outside of your comprehension or call it after defining it using ugly syntax like `if (lambda x: ...)(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
result = [i for i in range(10) if (lambda i: i%2 == 0)(i)]
```

Since lambda is an anonymous function, it is still a function.
You need to pass value to lambda.